# Linear homeomorphisms mapping an orthonormal basis into another orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $L^2(A)$ and $L^2(B)$. If $\{a_i\}$ is an o.n basis of $L^2(A)$, how many linear homeomorphisms $F:L^2(A) \to L^2(B)$  do there exist such that $Fa_i$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(B)$?

Is this a very restrictive assumption on the maps, if I wanted to discuss something about homeomorphism between the spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix one such $F$, the rest are found by composition with elements of the unitary group of $L^2(A)$. The unitary group of a Hilbert space (sometimes called the Hilbert group, $\mathrm{Hilb}\,(L^2(A))$) is very large: it contains a copy of every compact group. At the same time, it is contractible, by [Kuiper's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper's_theorem).

You may also be interested in MO discussions on the subject:

- [Compact subgroups of the unitary group of operators in a hilbert space](https://mathoverflow.net/q/121741)
- [Local cross sections for Unitary group in a hilbert space](https://mathoverflow.net/q/122894)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with groups at all so it is hard for me to understand the mathoverflow threads, but I will read some more. You say it's very large which is good news (I think). Are you aware of some result like: for every linear homemorphism $G$ between $L^2(A)$ and $L^2(B)$ there exists a $F$ mapping o.n basis to o.n basis that is arbitrarily close to $G$ in some norm.

Comment: @aere Of course, that would be false. If a map sends ONB to ONB, it is an *isometric isomorphism* between Hilbert spaces; it preserves the norm of every vector. In particular, its operator norm is $1$. If you take any linear bijective map between Hilbert spaces, it need not be close to such a thing. Try to test your conjectures on the example with both spaces being two-dimensional...